# Dot net nuke without module development?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

*This is more of an architecture level question.

I am new to DNN development , we are trying to build an e-commerce site which will showcase all the products which will be tied to our current order database.

Am I wrong in assuming that any custom development that I do via DNN would be in MODULE form ? I created few custom module (i.e. list of products) which would tie to database in code behind and display data from SQL. This seems to be very heavy approach if I have to make modules for every functionality.

Is there a better way here ? Can I (is it recommended) to directly change the DNN pages to accommodate this type of functionality ?

## UPDATED

Is it possible to do development without moduels ? i.e. provide code right in the html text editor or something. If i create new module from DNN template then it adds many files ....that is why it feels heavy

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is strongly recommended that you *not* directly change DNN.  This will make it very difficult to apply upgrades to DNN and cause headaches for whoever maintains the site after you.

The main extensibility point in DotNetNuke is the module.  The module is just some executable controls that you can place on any page.  It shouldn't be significantly heavier than any other approach you would take.  Whatever you want to do in DNN itself, you should be able to do in a module, and just place the module on a page.

You could also potentially have some of your functionality in the skin, rather than the module, if that is easier or makes more sense.  Generally, the skin has functionality that is shared across most pages in the site, and module are used to place specific content on specific pages.

If you're looking for something simpler, you might try using the core reports module, which will allow you to style the results of a query from the database (if you don't need the interactivity that a module would provide).

Comment: Hey bdukes

Thanks for the prompt reply. You made a great point about not changing the DNN code, that makes so much sense. 

Here is my confusion. I want to make product pages like ipad , iphnone etc. These pages will have some static data and some financial data like price , quantity, availability etc. 

For this do I have to create different moduels for each products ? Do I make one big dynamic module which can dynamically change in shape and form depending on whatever product page it is on ?

Comment: @hamilin11 has a good breakdown of the sorts of modules you would need.  I'd definitely recommend a dynamic module for listing products.

Answer (score 2):

**Your good options are as follows**

1. Build a separate Web Application for your e-commerce, but provide heavy inter-linking with the DNN site. With this method, DNN would be used for content.
2. Purchase a third party e-commerce module-set like SmithCart and try to configure it to meet your business model
3. Build custom DNN modules

Our current project utilizes option #3. We have 25,000 products and about 3,000 product listings with heavy customer-customization functionality.

While it might seem heavy, as in, a distinct module project per section of e-commerce, it doesn't have to be too complex.

**Example Modules:**

- Product Listing
- Product Details
- Shopping Cart
- Order Checkout (we split this into 4 modules)
- Search Module
- Search Results Module

You can use URLRewrites to map all your products to the same DNN Page/Module.

As a result, we really have very few non-content DNN pages.

In summary, it might feel a bit heavy, but with the proper design it can go rather smoothly in comparison to a separate web app.

Comment: Hey Hamlin,
Looks like you are doing exactly what we are trying to do. Can you provide more information ? How many modules do you have , can you also look at my comment in "bdukes" answer and provide more info there. I have also uploaded screenshot which shows sample module. 

In short we are trying to make website like "ACER" http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/home where you have bunch of products and also shopping cart integrated.

Comment: We have 40 modules altogether, but most are due to very specific business model constraints. You should really only need one module for all products assuming the layout is similar between all products. I would redirect users to an entirely different website for a mobile version. Example: mobile.stackoverflow.com. Sorry I can't be more specific at this time -- time constraints

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to use existing DNN features without module development. You can do it by adding a sub application in your folder.

For example, you can look at http://www.firstphera.com/GiftRegistry/Index.aspx, FirstPhera.com is a main dnn application and folder GiftRegistry is a pure asp.net sub application that uses dnn's providers to deal with database. Custom implementation of registration and login was the only thing that was challenge, everything else working fine.

But If are building an e-commerce application, at long term you will get benefit from module development way.

It is not strictly necessary that you create separate complected module like you shown in screen shot. If you look at blog module, it has feature like latest blogs, search blog, archives etc are all implemented in single module.

It is also possible to create a single module with related features in dotnetnuke using the technique called ModuleDefinitions. Look http://lakhlaniprashant.blogspot.com/2010/04/dotnetnuke-what-is-module-definition.html.

I would strongly recommend to visit [NBStore](http://nbstore.codeplex.com/) source code if you want to understand the e-commerce related module development in detail.

Please let know if you have any other question.